# how to append content in log file and upload into s3 after restating server using s3-streamlogger node module?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, winston

I am using winston node module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) for generting the log file and s3-streamlogger module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-streamlogger) for saving it into s3 server.

```
var s3_stream = new S3StreamLogger({
  bucket: bucket,
  access_key_id: accessKeyId,
  secret_access_key: secretAccessKey,
  name_format: "mylog.log"
});

var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ stream: s3_stream })
  ]
});

function formatArgs(args){
  return [util.format.apply(util.format, Array.prototype.slice.call(args))];
}
console.log = function(){
  logger.info.apply(logger, formatArgs(arguments));
};
```

My problem is that, log file is getting updated each time when server is restarted. I want that previous log should be their in log file and new log should be append on that. But this is not happening. I tried many things, but nothing works for me.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately s3-streamlogger can't do what you want: because of the way s3 works, it has to completely re-upload the file each time it is updated, so when your program is restarted the old file is completely overwritten.

I'd suggest you accept the creation of rotated log files with timestamped names, as s3-streamlogger does this for efficiency (as the file gets bigger its less efficient to re-upload it every time). If you use `name_format:'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-production-yourapp.log'` then you can use [tails3](https://github.com/coggle/tails3) to view the log files that s3-streamlogger creates as if they were a single file.